# Stuck on a step in a simple matrix calculus derivation

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I am trying to find the differential of $J$ below, in order to eventually find $\partial J/ \partial U$

$J = (I-Ur)^T(I-Ur)$

Let $a= I-Ur$

$\textbf{d}J = \textbf{d}(a^Ta) = \textbf{d}(a^T)a + a^T\textbf{d}a = (\textbf{d}a)^Ta + a^T\textbf{d}a = 2a^T\textbf{d}a$

Next, I try to find $\textbf{d}a$

$\textbf{d}a = \textbf{d}(I-Ur) =\textbf{d}(I) - \textbf{d}(Ur) = 0 - (\textbf{d}U)r - U\textbf{d}r$

Therefore, 
$\textbf{d}J = -2(I-Ur)^T((\textbf{d}U)r - U\textbf{d}r)$

Since I am interested in finding $\partial J/ \partial U$, I will treat $r$ as a constant, such that $\textbf{d}r=0$

So now I have:

$\textbf{d}J = -2(I-Ur)^T(\textbf{d}U)r$

I can't figure out how to bring the $\textbf{d}U$ term to the far right in order to turn this expression into the derivative that I want.

For example, if it were the case that I ended up with this expression instead:
$\textbf{d}J = -2(I-Ur)^Tr(\textbf{d}U)$

then I would have

$\partial J/ \partial U^T = -2(I-Ur)^Tr$
, and therefore:

$\partial J/ \partial U = -2\left((I-Ur)^Tr\right)^T = -2r^T(I-Ur)$

And I would be done! How do I turn the expression that I ended up with into the kind of expression that will give me the derivative I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [cyclic property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property) of the trace and the fact that the trace of a scalar 
(or is it a $1\times1$ matrix?) equals the scalar value. 
$$\eqalign{
dJ &= -2\,a^TdU\,r \\
  &= \operatorname{tr}(-2a^TdU\,r) \\
  &= \operatorname{tr}(-2ra^TdU) \\
}$$
The gradient is then [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities) to be 
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial U} = -2ra^T$$
$\ldots$or the transpose of this, depending on your preferred [layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) convention.

Comment: Ah, another case solved by the trace. Thank you Greg!